# Correct methodology using $g$-computation to estimate Average Treatment Effect on the Treated ($ATT$)?

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, treatment-effect, counterfactuals

I have a question about the $g$-computation methodology for estimating the Average Treatment Effect on the Treated ($ATT$) in the following [article](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-016-0282-4).

The authors recommend estimating the $ATT$ by first performing a regression model for $Y$ on the binary treatment $A$ and covariates $X$, then finding $E(Y^1|A=1)$ from the observed values of $Y|A=1$ and estimating the counterfactual $E(Y^0|A=1)$ by imputing the predicted value of $Y$ from the regression formula by substituting $A=0$ into the regression formula, but only for the observed $A=1$ records. So far so good.

For the next step, Wang et al. stack the records with the $E(Y^1|A=1)$ and $E(Y^0|A=1)$ estimates into a single dataset coupled with their $A$ values of 1 and 0, respectively. They then regress $Y$ on $A$, where $ATT$ is estimated from the regression coefficient on $A$.

Rather than regress $Y^*$ on $A$ why not simply compute the average of the difference $E(Y^1|A=1) - E(Y^0|A=1)$ for all records where $A=1$?

When I run a simulation the two methods return different results for the ATT point estimates - see R code below on a simulated dataset.

```
# Simulation data from "Targeted Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Causal Inference in    #
# Observational Studies", Schuler & Rose, 2016.                                           #
x1 <- rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.55)
x2 <- rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.3)

# Binary treatment variable
A <- rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=exp(-.5 + .75*x1 + x2)/(1 + exp(-.5 + .75*x1 + x2)))

# Outcome variable
Y <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=24 - 3*A + 3*x1 - 4*x2 + 7*x1*x2 + 5*A*x1 - 10*A*x2 + 15*A*x1*x2, sd=4.5)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(cbind(Y, A, x1, x2))

### Run linear regression
lm_test <- lm(Y ~ . + x1*x2 + A*x1 + A*x2 + A*x1*x2, data=df)

### Calculate ATT using g-computation. ###
# ATT = Expected difference between observed and counterfactual Y values at record level. #
df_trmt <- df[df$A==1,]
df_a0 <- df_trmt; df_a0$A = 0;
y_a0 = predict(lm_test, newdata=df_a0)
y_a1 = df_trmt$Y 

df_preds <- data.frame(cbind(df_trmt, y_a0, y_a1))

df_preds$att <- y_a1 - y_a0
mean(df_preds$att)
# [1] -0.284822 <==== ATT estimate
sqrt(var(df_preds$att)/length(df_preds$att))
# [1] 0.08707805

# Alternate g-computation calculation of ATT (based on Wang et al. (2017) article). #
df_a0_2 = data.frame(cbind(Y=y_a0, A=df_a0$A))
df_a1_2 = data.frame(cbind(Y=y_a1, A=df_trmt$A))
df_preds_2 <- data.frame(rbind(df_a0_2, df_preds_2))
lm_test_2 <- lm(Y ~ A, data=df2)
summary(lm_test_2)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = Y ~ A, data = df2)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -32.536  -4.337   0.592   5.399  24.712 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  25.1946     0.1265 199.207  < 2e-16 ***
#   A             0.5096     0.1723   2.957  0.00311 ** <==== ATT estimate
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 8.591 on 9998 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.0008738,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.0007739 
# F-statistic: 8.744 on 1 and 9998 DF,  p-value: 0.003113
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a bug in your code. I don't remember what I changed, but your code doesn't even run in a fresh `R` session. Logic demands that the results should be equal, and that is what I get:

```
set.seed(666)

# Simulation data from "Targeted Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Causal Inference in    #
# Observational Studies", Schuler & Rose, 2016.                                           #
x1 <- rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.55)
x2 <- rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.3)

# Binary treatment variable
A <- rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=exp(-.5 + .75*x1 + x2)/(1 + exp(-.5 + .75*x1 + x2)))

# Outcome variable
Y <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=24 - 3*A + 3*x1 - 4*x2 + 7*x1*x2 + 5*A*x1 - 10*A*x2 + 15*A*x1*x2, sd=4.5)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(cbind(Y, A, x1, x2))

### Run linear regression
lm_test <- lm(Y ~ . + x1*x2 + A*x1 + A*x2 + A*x1*x2, data=df)

### Calculate ATT using g-computation. ###
# ATT = Expected difference between observed and counterfactual Y values at record level. #
df_trmt <- df[df$A==1,]
df_a0 <- df_trmt; df_a0$A = 0;
y_a0 = predict(lm_test, newdata=df_a0)
y_a1 = df_trmt$Y 

df_preds <- data.frame(cbind(df_trmt, y_a0, y_a1))

df_preds$att <- y_a1 - y_a0

# Alternate g-computation calculation of ATT (based on Wang et al. (2017) article). #
df_a0_2 = data.frame(cbind(Y=y_a0, A=0))
df_a1_2 = data.frame(cbind(Y=y_a1, A=1))
df_preds_2 <- data.frame(rbind(df_a0_2, df_a1_2))
lm_test_2 <- lm(Y ~ A, data=df_preds_2)

summary(lm_test_2)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = Y ~ A, data = df_preds_2)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -33.951  -2.485   1.001   4.143  24.921 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  26.0230     0.1060 245.597   <2e-16 ***
#   A            -0.3081     0.1498  -2.056   0.0398 *  
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 7.911 on 11146 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.0003792,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.0002896 
# F-statistic: 4.229 on 1 and 11146 DF,  p-value: 0.03977
mean(y_a1 - y_a0)
# [1] -0.3081427
```

The standard errors don't agree, but of course **neither** standard error is correct, so this isn't much of a concern to me.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Not sure where I messed up in my code. Yea the standard errors aren't correct - in the paper the authors used bootstrapping to estimate the SE.